# get queries for `like` in cshtml

Tags: sql, razor, asp.net-webpages

I have the code for searching information in my database:

```
var querysearchcommand = "SELECT * FROM student, forum_thread, notice where student_username like '%@0%' or student_firstname like '%@0%' or student_lastname like '%@0%' or forum_thread_title like '%@0%' or notice_body like '%@0%'";

var querysearchdata = db.Query(querysearchcommand, query);
```

The result always shows nothing whereas I have a student with firstname containing the letter 'a'.

Can anybody please help me about what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm sorry to ask this but are you really writing your query in .cshtml file?

Comment: Yes. Why? Will there be a problem if I do so?

Comment: Not a problem as such. Its just a **bad bad practice**.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing it out though! I'm just a newbie and will keep your suggestion in mind!

Comment: You seem to be making use of ASP.NET MVC. The whole theme behind MVC is ***Seperation of concerns***. The presentation can be oblivious of the data storage and business logic and do only what it is supposed to do : **display**.

Comment: In this case, your presentation would contain data manipulation logic thereby destroying the main tenets of MVC - ***Seperation of concerns***. Also, your code will not be testable - one of the other advantages of MVC.

Comment: And just think about it, what advantages are you getting by putting the queries here rather than say at the controller level or the repository level. That's the reason why its a ***bad bad practice*** and not just a ***bad practice***.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny Even if not specified (I have edited it) the question refers to the Asp.Net Web Pages framework. In this framework there is no separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to concatenate the string used in the `LIKE` comparison

```
var querysearchcommand = "SELECT * FROM student, forum_thread, notice where student_username like '%' + @0 + '%'"; // and so on
```

Comment: It is giving this error `Input string was not in a correct format`

Comment: did you copy paste verbatim? I was missing a closing `"` before.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like

```
var querysearchcommand = @"SELECT * FROM student, forum_thread, notice 
    where student_username like @0 or student_firstname like @0 or 
    student_lastname like @0 or forum_thread_title like @0 or 
    notice_body like @0";

var querysearchdata = db.Query(querysearchcommand, "%" + query + "%");
```

Notice the @ before the querysearchcommand value: it creates a Verbatim string, that can span multiple lines.